# how to resize image programatically with theme image

Tags: media

i need to resize image in my module output, but this code seems not working

```
$file = file_load($fid);
$image = theme('image', array('style_name'=> 'small', 'path' => $file->uri, 'alt' => 'user picture'));
```

i am getting my image from database. i have created media type **small** to scale my image,
but **style_name** does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`theme_image_style()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) for that one:

```
$image = theme('image_style', array(
  'style_name'=> 'small', 
  'path' => $file->uri, 
  'alt' => 'user picture'
));
```